# Embedded Google maps Vs API V3

Tags: google-maps

What is the difference between displaying a google map as below embedded VS Google API 2 or 3.

```
 <iframe width="600" height="500"  src="https://maps.google.com/maps?

 q=-43.867487,121.20699&t=m&z=14&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 

 marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Are the limitations as not using any key to display the map.

In terms of licence costing how this differ ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/usagelimits/?utm_referrer=v3#goingover

Answer (score 3):

The Google Maps API is used to greatly customize the end-user experience with the maps. It can be used to create an entire interactive platform to view or manipulate your data. It can encompass all of the features of embedded maps, but requires considerably more Javascript experience.

Embedded maps provide a rather simple version where people can use the standard layout and include points, routes, etc... I understand there was a new [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) released in March.

Both offer free levels of usage, but with high daily traffic, you will have to start coughing up the dough. More details can be found on their intro page, https://developers.google.com/maps/web/.